# Alternate options for import to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, import, sql-server-2012

I'm working on automating daily imports to my SQL Server (2012) database, but my IT admins are being...unhelpful in implementing the options I'm familiar with.  Namely `BULK INSERT`, `OPENROWSET`, and to some extent SSIS packages.

I know what the blocking issues are for `BULK INSERT` and `OPENROWSET` but IT has declined to address them.  They're working on the SSIS issues, but I'm not confident they'll be done anytime soon, so I'm looking for other options.

So, are there other programmatic import options besides these three?  Specifically for flat `.txt` files and `.xlsx`

Comment: How about `powershell`? scripts?

Comment: @Hackerman No way am I getting command line privileges from my IT.  Their opinions on user privileges are downright paranoid.

Comment: For importing text files you can use [bcp](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx)